# mysql counting all of each dupplicate in a table

Tags: mysql

Good Day I'm cuurently having problem I don't know why I cant do it with count

I have a column say...

```
colx 
aaa  
aaa
aaa
aaa
bbb
bbb
bbb
bbb
ccc
ccc
eee
```

I want the output to be

```
Result No_of_Repeats
aaa    4
bbb    4
ccc    2
eee    1
```

Comment: It's not obvious how, if at all, you want the results ordered.

Comment: hmm order by the highest my bad bro :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a simple `COUNT` with `GROUP BY` to get the count by group.

```
SELECT colx result, COUNT(1) No_of_Repeats 
FROM table1
GROUP BY colx
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
```

[A simple SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7dec5/5).

Answer (score 0):

You have to take main query in temp and then order by the count. Like this:

```
$q = "SELECT temp.* FROM (SELECT colx as Result, COUNT(colx) as No_of_Repeats FROM tbl_name GROUP BY colx) as temp ORDER BY temp.No_of_Repeats DESC";
```

Comment: dude it returned MySQL said:
#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

:/ just copied you code ang changed variables :/ I actually didn't know there was a temp query like assigning records in a variable?

Comment: actually, first I forget `as temp` statement, can you please copy once again and check ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple Query...

```
select colx as Result,count(colx) as No_of_Repeats from tbl group by colx order by No_of_Repeats desc;
```

Comment: how to order by max count?

Comment: @Pathik Vejani ...its coming directly as values are in order so I have not considered that scenario

Comment: Yes, this is also possible. But ordering according to count is also good :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 select colx as result,count(colx) as No_of_Repeats from table1 group by colx;
```